# How to develop on installed gems

Tags: rubygems

Currently, I have the stable version of a gem (specifically, `nanoc3`) installed with RubyGems. However, I would like to fork the developer's repository to hack on some stuff. What's the recommended way to have a gem installed (it doesn't actually have to be *installed* in a technical sense, just somewhere that I can use it if I need to without redownloading) but still work on its repository (and have the repository's `lib` directory loaded into the Ruby path)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing was building the gem inside the repo, installing it with `gem install`, and then deleting `~/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/nanoc3-3.1.0a1` and symlinking it to the repository root.